# Three.js: ways to reduce file size of models?

Tags: json, three.js

Currently I use the ObjectLoader to load all my models into the scene. I also use the Three.js editor to apply my textures. The way I do it currently is by exporting a OBJ file from 3Ds Max and importing it into the Three.js online editor where I then add the texture.

The OBJ file is around 30mb but the exported JSON file is almost 100mb. How can there be such a huge difference? The texture size is very low so that isn't the reason. Does anyone have any insight on this or have a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just load the .obj file into three.js using OBJLoader ?

Comment: I only do this because the editor is quite convenient for applying the texture. I've never used the OBJ loader before but I think I'll give it a try. Also is there a way to further reduce the file size?  Thanks.

Comment: Use the [converters and exporters that are in the three.js repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils).

Comment: Ok thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your origin obj file may not contain normals and UV lists. This fact alone could easily push a file to 300% size when you add textures.

OBJ is a legacy line by line format. JSON is a multidimensional object, with all that entails. Arrays and Objects in JSON carry significant footprints such as commas, quotes, brackets and significant line breaks when not considered, as well as potential for repeated tokens. The three.js developers have been very clever in the 3d json format not to repeat meta information.

In contrast, the OBJ format uses only simple one and two letter indicators at each line with space delimited values on each line.

For example:

```
f v1 v2 v3
```

Although streamlined, This makes OBJ files more difficult to work with and there are loading limitations with ObjLoader and ObjLoader2 in three.js that don't exist when loading a json file.

Which filetype you choose is up to you. Threejs has loaders and exporters for various formats, such as STL and Collada, and includes obj export.

[Exporters](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/exporters)

[Loaders](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/loaders)

In either case of using json or obj, when serving 3d models to the browser, it is critical that your server is setup properly with JIT GZIP. See [this decent article](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) I just found via google. This will streamline serving of 3d data.

The proper way to go about reduction of 3d model size for delivery on the web or in a game is to [use mesh decimation plugins](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-99A80959-7100-440E-BC06-17E79E13F8A5-htm.html).

Not that it matters, but I prefer using OBJ throughout my data flow for compliance with various 3d toolsets since it's so widely supported.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce (a lot) the obj file size by rounding numbers up to 1 or 2 decimal places.
The [guruware OBJexporter](http://www.guruware.at/main/index.html) can do this automatically for you. Just enter 1 or 2 in the Precision input.

Comment: in which case it might be best to just go with binary?

Comment: big files and high speed encoding/decoding?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion