# opening threejs Compressed OBJ in memory for render

Tags: vue.js, three.js, compression, vue-component

im working on site created with **vuejs**  which render many object in **webgl**(**threejs**),

i have 7 obj with minimum **7mb** file size therefor it take along time to load.

but if i **tgz** all file together it would be around 4mb.

so my question is :

can i download **tgz** in memory extract them and load them in to my **threejs** ?

here is my threejs loader with draco compressor

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
objLoader.setPath(codepenAssetUrl1);
objLoader.load( 'wtc2.obj', function ( object ) {   
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            let scale = 1.3;

            let area = new THREE.Box3();
                area.setFromObject( child );
            let yOffset = (area.max.y * scale) / 2;

            child.geometry.scale(scale,scale,scale);
            rocketPoints = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry(child.geometry, particleCount);
            createVertices(rocketParticles, rocketPoints, yOffset, 2);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can just set your server to serve gzipped files, send the correct headers, and the browser will decompress them automatically. You'd have 4 gzipped files instead of 1 but it should be a similar amount of compression. [How to configure your server to send gzipped files depends on the server](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+serve+gzipped+files).

Comment: I'd also look at your float lengths in the obj file. They may be long, and a web view usually doesn't need accuracy beyond 3. This can dramatically reduce your obj file size. There are other ways to optimize a model which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144656/three-js-ways-to-reduce-file-size-of-models/45149572#45149572

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your server to serve gzip (in which case the decompression is handled silently by the browser) or you use a utility such as [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to unzip your archive at runtime.

I would also suggest considering a more efficient / modern file format than OBJ, such as glTF in its binary form (glb).

Comment: i test all sort of format and compression draco/gltf/etc with my setting smallest copression size achieved by obj, I dont know why but gltf output is about 40mb but obj out puts only 4mb or less tested in blender,rhino with all sort of plugin